# updating rails 5.1 to 5.2 freezes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to update my rails application from 5.1 to 5.2 using `rails app:update`.

However the execution of the command gets stuck after displaying the following lines
below.

```
rails app:update
   identical  config/boot.rb
   exist  config
conflict  config/routes.rb
in/config/routes.rb ? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

I have allowed this for close to an hour, but nothing seem to come up.

Any suggestions or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what was your input?

Comment: please input to what?

Comment: [y n a q d h] y for yes, n for no, a for abroad, q for quite, d for diff, h for help

Comment: Ok. Had no idea i was been asked to input any of that, please which option should i use, and what do each one do please.

Comment: there is a conflict in your route file. first, view diff using "d" and decide yes or no

Comment: I have entered 'd' but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188364/discussion-between-oshanz-and-wokoro-douye-samuel).